# JavaScript to access HTML values set from a Modal Box

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to understand how to access an HTML value that is set in the DOM after a Modal Box is used to select an image from a file store.

Before the Modal Box is fired the following HTML code is in the DOM:

```
<div class="field">
  <input class="browse" id="tileOneImage_csBrowse" value="Browse Content Collection" title="Browse Content Collection" type="button">
  <input id="tileOneImage_selectedCSFile" name="tileOneImage_CSFile" value="" type="hidden">
  <input id="tileOneImage_selectedCSFileName" name="tileOneImage_linkTitle" type="hidden">
  <input id="tileOneImage_selectedCSFilePath" name="tileOneImage_CSFilePath" value="" type="hidden">
  <input id="tileOneImage_selectedCSFileSize" type="hidden">
  <input id="copyToPrivateDoc" value="false" type="hidden">
</div>
```

After the user selects an image using the Modal Box the value params are populated:

```
<div class="field">
  <input class="disabled" id="tileOneImage_csBrowse" value="Browse Content Collection" title="Browse Content Collection" disabled="" type="button">
  <input id="tileOneImage_selectedCSFile" name="tileOneImage_CSFile" value="/xid-1602_1" type="hidden">
  <input id="tileOneImage_selectedCSFileName" name="tileOneImage_linkTitle" value="promo2.svg" type="hidden">
  <input id="tileOneImage_selectedCSFilePath" name="tileOneImage_CSFilePath" value="/xid-1602_1" type="hidden">
  <input id="tileOneImage_selectedCSFileSize" value="4967" type="hidden">
  <input id="copyToPrivateDoc" value="false" type="hidden">
</div>
```

My JavaScript code is:

```
var imageOneValue;
var finalImageOnePath;
var serverPath = document.getElementById('serverUrl').value;

document.getElementById('tileOneImage_csBrowse').addEventListener('click', promo1Path, true);

function promo1Path(e) {

    imageOneValue = document.getElementById('tileOneImage_selectedCSFilePath').value;
    finalImageOnePath = serverPath + "/bbcswebdav" + imageOneValue;

    document.getElementById('promo1').src = finalImageOnePath;                          
    document.getElementById('tileOnePath').setAttribute('value', finalImageOnePath); 
}
```

To open the Modal Box the user presses the `Browse` button once. I want to display the chosen image and file path in the page at id locations `promo1` and `tileOnePath` after the Modal Box has closed. But my code currently requires the `Browse` button to be clicked a second time to populate fully with the value param.

I have tried changing the `EventListener` to change and focus, but I think I should be targeting something else - any advice?

Comment: what library or plugin are you using to that Modal Box?

Comment: Depending on the library or plugin you should be able to listen to hide/hidden/close event

Comment: No Library or plugin - it is built into the system application using JavaScript.

Comment: @RakeshGR there are submit  or cancel buttons <input id="bottom_pickerSubmit" class="submit button-1" name="bottom_pickerSubmit" role="button" value="Submit" onclick="resourcePicker.submitSingleResourceSelection();" type="submit">

Comment: If you are using your own custom js for modal, you should be able to add a call back for the submit action or add a custom event to be called on close/submit